# How to change legend title and colors in R

Tags: r

I have the following code written:

```
dev.new()
ggplot(Depot)+geom_path(mapping=aes(x=time, y=C1,color="Central Compartment"))+
  geom_path(mapping=aes(x=time,y=C2, color="Peripheral Compartment"))+
  xlab("Time (hours)")+ylab("Concentration (mg/L)")`
```

which gives me the graph below. However, I'd like to be able to change the colors from the defaults that are being assigned, as well as change the legend title from "colour" to something more relevant to my graph.

[image: Graph generated]

Comment: Please share a sample of your data `Depot` using `dput(Depot)` and paste the output editing your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the title of the legend with `labs(color = "Your label")` and specify the colours with `scale_color_manual(values = c("color1", "color2"))`

Here's an example with an approximation of your data:

```r
ggplot(Depot) +
  geom_path(aes(x = time, y = C1, color = "Central Compartment")) + 
  geom_path(aes(x = time, y = C2, color = "Peripheral Compartment")) + 
  xlab("Time (hours)") +
  ylab("Concentration (mg/L)") +
  labs(colour = "Compartment") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("forestgreen", "deepskyblue4"))
```

[image]

---

**Data used:**

```r
time  <- seq(0, 6, 0.1)
C1    <- 12 * dgamma(time, 1.8)
C2    <- 5  * dgamma(time, 3.5)
Depot <- data.frame(time, C1, C2)
```